# How to exclude specific phrase from wordpress search

Tags: wordpress

I have a repeatable phrase in some pages and posts which I want to exclude from search results.

Is there a filter for this in WordPress?

Comment: This link may be helpful to you. : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56281/do-not-allow-to-search-certain-words

Comment: Great Help Thanks